# Finding wrong escape of WMI query

Tags: c#, wmi-query

I somewhere did a wrong escape of wmi query, can someone help fixing it? Because it shows Invalid query

```
string deviceid = "Disk #0, Partition #0";
        string antecedent = @"\\" + Environment.MachineName + "\\root\\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=\"" + deviceid + "\"";
        ManagementObjectSearcher assosiaciation_query2 = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select Dependent from Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition where Antecedent = \"" + antecedent + "\"");
        foreach (ManagementObject assosiaciation_query_data2 in assosiaciation_query2.Get())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dependent: " + assosiaciation_query_data2["Dependent"]);
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use the VisualStudio debugger, it will help you finding where your error is... We are *not* a debugging service

Answer (score 0):

You put 2 doublequote inside 2 other doublequote, and that broke your code. You should use WMI  escape code inside your antecedent string:

```
string antecedent = @"\\" + Environment.MachineName + "\\root\\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=\\\"" + deviceid + "\\\"";
```

When WMI receive the command it should be something like that:

> \"yourdeviceid\"

that inserted into 2 apex shoud work correctly :) Example:

```
Mycommand"myOtherCommand\"myvalue\""
```

---

*EDIT*:
I completely misunderstant your goal, sorry, <s>there is an error in your query, because '#' is MySQL Wildcard that mess your query (is MySql inline comment),</s>
Nope, it doesn't works even if i use where Ascendent like 'aaa', idk why your where condition mess up the code :/.

If you use the following piece of code it works:

```
    string query = "select * from Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition";
    string antecedent = @"\\" + Environment.MachineName + "\\root\\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=\"" + deviceid + "\"";
        ManagementObjectSearcher moSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
        ManagementObjectCollection moCollection = moSearch.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moCollection)
        {
            if (string.Equals(mo["Antecedent"].ToString(), antecedent))
                Console.WriteLine("Dependent: " + mo["Dependent"]);
        }
```

Comment: Finnal antecent variable should look like this \\PC-NAME\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #1, Partition #0" @Legion and if I put antecedent variable to Console.WriteLine(antecedent); I get same result as I looking, but i believe somewhere in wmi query it self is wrong escape

Comment: ok, so your string should be: \\PC-NAME\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=\"Disk #1, Partition #0\" because is inside another "string" (doublequotes) :)

That's the magic --> \" (that in a standard C# string become \\\" becase you need c# escape codes too).

Comment: I readed like 10 times your comment, tried and it is not escaping.

Comment: I try to explain better, your antecedent string has nothing wrong, if you use it as is you've no problems, but if you put it as argument to another command you need to use WMI escape codes, that why all seems correct but when you use it it doesn't work :)
P.S.: \\PC-NAME\ <-- here i think you need to use escape codes too: \\\\PC-NAME\\

Comment: ok I will show you output: http://www.part.lt/img/43670574ffcd8d5393b0f15ae5ba5b64338.png First line is antecedent, second line is what I want to get. as you can see they are same, unless in wmi everything is diffrent. and if i put query code in console i get: select Dependent from Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition where Antecedent = '\\PC-NAME\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #0, Partition #0"', i changed from double quetes to single since i think wmi think first double quetes are parameter i looking for.

Comment: You say it, in WMI everything is different :D
WMI has his own escape code(that just for your luck are the same of c#). so you need to use WMI escape code if you put doubleapex inside other 2 doubleapex

Comment: To got your goal when you print antecedent in console you need to see that:


\\PC-NAME\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=\"Disk #1, Partition #0\"

Comment: string antecedent = @"\\" + Environment.MachineName + "\\root\\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=\\\"" + deviceid + "\\\""; in console it outputs with "\ but query still invalid. Also what happens with backslashes in code do I also need escape them?

Comment: edit my answer, i misunderstand what you're trying to do since start sry.

Answer (score 0):

Ok since in mysql you could use LIKE to find simillar tables, also I read that is possible https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392263%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 to use LIKE in wmi query

```
string deviceid = "Disk #0, Partition #0"; ManagementObjectSearcher assosiaciation_query2 = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select Dependent from Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition where Antecedent LIKE '%" + deviceid + "%'");
```

So ant still it show that query is invalid

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string Mtd_GetDriveLetterWithLabel(string DriveLabel)
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher DriveLabelQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher(" SELECT * FROM Win32_Volume WHERE Label = '" + DriveLabel + "' ");

    string DriveLetter = "";
    foreach (ManagementObject DriveLabels in DriveLabelQuery.Get())
    {
        DriveLetter = DriveLabels["DriveLetter"].ToString();
    }
    return DriveLetter;
}




public static int Mtd_GetDiskNumberWithLetter(string DriveLetter)
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher DriveLetterGeneralQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition");
    ManagementObjectCollection DriveLetterCollection = DriveLetterGeneralQuery.Get();

    string Dependent = @"\\" + Environment.MachineName + "\\root\\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID=\"" + DriveLetter + "\"";
    String DiskNumberTxt = "";
    foreach (ManagementObject DiskNumbers in DriveLetterCollection)
    {
        if ((DiskNumbers["Dependent"].ToString()) == Dependent)
        {
            DiskNumberTxt = DiskNumbers["Antecedent"].ToString();
        }
    }

    int From = DiskNumberTxt.IndexOf("Disk #") + "Disk #".Length;
    int To = DiskNumberTxt.IndexOf(",");
    String DiskNumberTrim = DiskNumberTxt.Substring(From, To - From);

    int DiskNumber = Int32.Parse(DiskNumberTrim);
    return DiskNumber;
}




public static string Mtd_GetSerialNumberWithDiskNumber(int DiskNumber)
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher SerialNumberQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia");
    ManagementObjectCollection SerialNumberCollection = SerialNumberQuery.Get();

    string Tag = @"\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE" + DiskNumber;
    String SerialNumberTxt = "";

    foreach (ManagementObject SerialNumbers in SerialNumberCollection)
    {
        if ((SerialNumbers["Tag"].ToString()) == Tag)
        {
            SerialNumberTxt = SerialNumbers["SerialNumber"].ToString();
        }
    }
    return SerialNumberTxt;
}



string DriveLabel = "DATA";
 
string DriveLetter = Mtd_GetDriveLetterWithLabel(DriveLabel);
            Console.WriteLine(DriveLetter);
                       
int DiskNumber = Mtd_GetDiskNumberWithLetter(DriveLetter);
Console.WriteLine(DiskNumber);

string DiskSerialNumber = Mtd_GetSerialNumberWithDiskNumber(DiskNumber);
Console.WriteLine(DiskSerialNumber);
```